# support multi language websites on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, multilingual

Is there a way in Tomcat to automatically return a file depending on the "accept-language" header field of a http-request?
(for example to return a location specific html-file)

Or do I have to read the "accept-language" header field by my own and return a redirect to the corresponding file?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[Tomcat 3.3 has StaticInterceptor](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/serverxml.html#StaticInterceptor).  I don't see an equivalent for Tomcat 7.